# Advice regarding solving ill-conditioned systems

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, condition-number

I start from a well-conditioned linear system $AX=B$ where $A$, $X$ and $B$ are complex square matrices of the same shape ($M$,$M$) and `cond(A)=1`

Then I need to solve linear systems that derive from the one above, where I replace some columns of A and B as follows: given a bit string $b$ of length $M$, if `b[i]` is 1 I replace the $i$-th column of $A$ with minus the $i$-th column of the identity matrix and if it's 0 I replace the i-th column of B with the same.

Example for $M=3$ (here the entries of A and B are integers for illustration):

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
4&5&6\\
7&8&9\\
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
B = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&3\\
4&5&6\\
7&8&9\\
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
b = [0,0,1]
$$
Using this bit string new system is $AX=B$ with
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}
1&2&0\\
4&5&0\\
7&8&-1\\
\end{pmatrix}
\qquad
B = \begin{pmatrix}
-1&0&3\\
0&-1&6\\
0&0&9\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The issue is that almost always the derived system is badly conditioned (cond(A) is anywhere between 1 and 100 in my tests) and eventually the algorithm I'm developing which relies on solving for `X` for all bit strings gives incorrect results.

I've tried solving with QR decomposition, but it didn't help much. Given the particular nature of the derived system, what else could I try?

Comment: You seem to have done the reverse of what your bit string [1,1,0] indicated

Comment: A condition number of 100 isn't at all large.  In what sense are the solutions that you're getting "wrong"?

Comment: They are wrong in the sense that the solutions with respect to all the bit strings are combined recursively so the errors, albeit not large, accumulate quickly

Comment: Thanks Ben, yes there’s a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll consider the case where b is a sequence of 1's followed by 0's so that $A$ has its first columns removed, and $B$ has its last columns removed; the approach can be generalized from there. The resulting matrices can be written as
$$
A_1 = \pmatrix{-I & A_{12}\\0 & A_{22}}, \quad B_1 = \pmatrix{B_{11} & 0\\B_{21} & -I}.
$$
We can multiply $A_1$ by a matrix from the right to get a new system:
$$
\left[\pmatrix{-I & A_{12}\\0 & A_{22}}
\pmatrix{I & A_{12}\\0 & I}\right] 
\left[\pmatrix{I & A_{12}\\0 & I}^{-1}X\right] = \pmatrix{B_{11} & 0\\B_{21} & -I} \implies\\
\underbrace{\pmatrix{-I & 0\\0 & A_{22}}}_{A_2} 
\underbrace{\left[\pmatrix{I & A_{12}\\0 & I}^{-1}X\right]}_{X_2} = 
\pmatrix{B_{11} & 0\\B_{21} & -I}
$$
From there, the matrix $A_2$ should be relatively well conditioned (cf. [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/264586/34894) for instance), and the solution process therefore more straightforward. However, we can actually use the structure of $A_2$ to make the solution process easier. Breaking $X_2$ up vertically, we have
$$
\pmatrix{-I & 0\\0 & A_{22}} \pmatrix{X_{21}\\X_{22}} = \pmatrix{B_{11} & 0\\ B_{21} & -I} \implies\\
\pmatrix{-X_{21}\\
A_{22}X_{22}} = \pmatrix{B_{11} & 0\\B_{21} & -I}\implies\\
\begin{cases}
X_{21} = -\pmatrix{B_{11} & 0}\\
A_{22}X_{22} = \pmatrix{B_{21} & -I},
\end{cases}
$$
which leaves you with only one, smaller system to solve in order to build $X_2$. From there, we have
$$
X_2 = \pmatrix{I & A_{12}\\0 & I}^{-1}X \implies\\
X = \pmatrix{I & A_{12}\\0 & I} X_2 = \pmatrix{X_{21} + A_{12}X_{22}\\ X_{22}}.
$$

---

Here's how we can generalize this approach. Let $i_1<i_2<\cdots<i_k$ denote the indices $i$ for which $b[i] = 1$, and let $j_1<j_2<\cdots<j_{n-k}$ denote the rest. Let $P$ denote the matrix whose columns are the columns of the identity matrix, but in the order $i_1,i_2,\dots,i_k,j_1,j_2,\dots,j_{n-k}$.

I claim that the matrix $P$ is a permutation matrix (so that $P^{-1} = P^T$) designed so that $AP$ and $BP$ are of the correct form for the above approach. With that, we can solve the system
$$
(AP)\underbrace{(P^{-1}XP)}_{X_3} = BP.
$$
for $X_3$, then recover $X = PX_3P^T$.

Comment: amazing  I'm gonna try this out and get back to you

Comment: it worked! thanks :)